# Extending [a,b] to the real line by a conform mapping in ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, chain-rule

- We have an ODE on [a,b] as follows.
  \begin{equation}\left\{\begin{array}{l}
  -u^{\prime \prime}(x)+p(x) u^{\prime}(x)+q(x) u(x)=f(x), \quad x \in[a, b] \\
  u(a)=u(b)=0
  \end{array}\right.\end{equation}
- I want to extend to [a,b] to the real line by a conform mapping $\psi(t)$.

For $l$ which is a non-negative real number, define the transformation of the variable
$$
v(t)=\left(\left(\phi^{\prime}\right)^{l} u\right) \circ \psi(t)=\left(\phi^{\prime}(\psi(t))\right)^{l} u(\psi(t))
$$
A calculation by using the chain rule and $x=\psi(t)$ leads to the equalities
$$
\begin{array}{l}
u(x)=\frac{1}{\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)\right)^{l}} v(t) \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} u(x)}{\mathrm{d} x}=\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)\right)^{1-l} \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}+\left(\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)\right)^{-l}\right)^{\prime} v(t) \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} u(x)}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}=\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)\right)^{2-l} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} v}{\mathrm{d} t^{2}}+(1-2 l)\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)\right)^{-l} \phi^{\prime \prime}(x) \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}+\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)^{-l}\right)^{\prime \prime} v(t)
\end{array}
$$

***- Substituting the equations to an original ODE, we have a new ODE on $(-\infty,\infty)$***
$$
\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)\right)^{2-l} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} v}{\mathrm{d} t^{2}}+(1-2 l)\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)\right)^{-l} \phi^{\prime \prime}(x) \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}+\left(\phi^{\prime}(x)^{-l}\right)^{\prime \prime} v(t)=f_{2}(x)
$$
In addition, $v(t)$ satisfies the following conditions:
$$
\lim _{t \rightarrow \pm \infty} v(t)=0
$$
which follow from $\psi(-\infty)=0, \psi(\infty)=1$

****My questions:****

In fact, I have a solution above, just I need some explanation for the following questions.

**1-** What is the logic behind selecting the $v(t)$ as follows
$$
v(t)=\left(\left(\phi^{\prime}\right)^{l} u\right) \circ \psi(t)
$$
and how to get the following
$\left(\left(\phi^{\prime}\right)^{l} u\right) \circ \psi(t)=\left(\phi^{\prime}(\psi(t))\right)^{l} u(\psi(t))$

**2-** Could you explain more explicitly how to get $\frac{du(x)}{dx}$ and  $\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}$ by using chain rule?

Best regards,

from a Ph.D. student at mathematics.

Comment: Please type the equations with MathJax, also you don't have to bold all your words https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yes, I did the editings.